# Order when using v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-for

When using the v-for to iterate over an array like so:

```
<ul id="example-1">
  <li v-for="item in items">
     {{ item.message }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

The elements are ordered underneath each other:

- List Item with index 1
- List Item with index 2
- List Item with index ...
- List Item with index n

Is there a way to add the item from the current iteration above the last item?

- List Item with index n
- List Item with index ...
- List Item with index 2
- List Item with index 1

Thank you very much!

Comment: if all you want to change the order of array no matter what then simply use .reverse() method of array [1,2,3].reverse() => [3,2,1]

Comment: thanks for your answer. I already thought about that. The problem is that during runtime the array changes. So this is not an option. Also I tried unshift instead of push. But still, the element is rendered below the items.

Comment: Sort your items when you load them.

ajaxcall().then((res) => this.items = res.data.sort('...'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a second array to "stock" your reversed data and use [`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) (instead of `push`) to put every new element at the beginning of the "reversed" array:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      items: ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"],
      reversedItems: []
    } 
  },
  mounted() {
    this.reversedItems = this.items.reverse()
  },
  methods: {
    loadItem(){
      let i = this.items.length
      this.items.unshift("item " + (i + 1))
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in reversedItems">{{ item }}</li>
  </ul>
  <button @click="loadItem">Load item</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Except that… when you do `items.unshift("item4")`, `items` array should become `["item4", "item1", "item2", "item3"]`, hence the display should be from top to bottom: item3, item2, item1, item4 whereas your code does: item4, item3, item2, item1.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) of your `items`, that reverses the array (without mutating it in place in case it is used as a `prop`, or in order to keep its order as initially declared): `reversedItems() { return this.items.slice().reverse(); }`

Code example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      items: ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    reversedItems() {
      // Reverse a COPY of the array to avoid messing with its initial order.
      return this.items.slice().reverse();
    },
  },
  methods: {
    loadItem() {
      const i = this.items.length;
      // Append to the end of the array in a simple approach,
      // and let the computed property re-order the array.
      this.items.push("item " + (i + 1));
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in reversedItems">{{ item }}</li>
  </ul>
  <button @click="loadItem">Load item</button>
</div>
```

Note that Vue patches [array methods (like `reverse`)](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection) when applied on reactive data (like variables you declare in `data`), so that the result is also reactive. That is why the `reversedItems` data in @sovalina's answer becomes reactive to `items` modifications, whereas it is assigned only once when the component is mounted.